# return when asynchronous task has completed

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I'd need a function to wait until the asynchronous task has completed and then return.

In my example, I'm getting undefined returned from the "execute" method:

```
var result = myClass.execute(obj);  //undefined
```

How can I get the actual result returned?

```
return declare(null, {
        constructor: function (obj) {
            this.mapServiceUrl = obj.mapServiceUrl;
            this.geometry_json = obj.geometry_json || undefined;
            this.where = obj.where || "1=1";
        },

        execute: function () {
            var queryTask = new QueryTask(this.mapServiceUrl),
                query = new Query()
            ;

            query.returnGeometry = true;
            query.outFields = ["RDUWI"];

            if (this.geometry_json) {
                query.spatialRelationship = Query.SPATIAL_REL_INTERSECTS;
                query.geometry = Polygon(this.geometry_json);
            };

            query.where = this.where;
            var deferred = queryTask.execute(query);
            deferred.then(function (featureSet) {
                return featureSet;
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: You cannot.  You have to return the deferred and put the "then" outside execute.  myClass.execute(obj).then(f(featureSet){}).

Comment: @ca0v: Thank you! Could you provide a link where this is explained? Then move it to the answers please.

Comment: It will be intuitive once you understand deferred.  Indirect docs would be for all and when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the c# await keyword, which does not exist in javascript:

> The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to
>   suspend the execution of the method until the awaited task completes.
>   The task represents ongoing work. The asynchronous method in which
>   await is used must be modified by the async keyword. Such a method,
>   defined by using the async modifier, and usually containing one or
>   more await expressions, is referred to as an async method.

The closest you can get to making this type of code transparent is to use [when](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/when.html).  Docs state:

> dojo/when is designed to make it easier to merge coding of synchronous
>   and asynchronous threads. Accepts promises but also transparently
>   handles non-promises. If no callbacks are provided returns a promise,
>   regardless of the initial value. Also, foreign promises are converted.
>
> If callbacks are provided and the initial value is not a promise, the
>   callback is executed immediately with no error handling. Returns a
>   promise if the initial value is a promise, or the result of the
>   callback otherwise.